# ReactJS: How to avoid redirect when using Select inside Link component in Navbar?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-select

I've a `Select` component inside `<Link>` component of the `Navbar' below:

```
const Navbar = (props) => {

    return (
        <Link to='/'>
            <div className='navbar'>

                <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="App Name"/>
                <h1 className='app_name'>My App Name</h1>
                <BaseCurrencySelect baseCurrency={props.baseCurrency} stateChanger={props.stateChanger}/>
            </div>
        </Link>
    )
}
```

And here is my `BaseCurrencySelect` component:

```
export default function BaseCurrencySelect(props) {

    const [baseCurrency, setBaseCurrency] = React.useState(props.baseCurrency);

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        let selectedCurrency = CurrencyUtils.getCurrencyFromId(event.target.value)
        setBaseCurrency(selectedCurrency);
        props.stateChanger(selectedCurrency);
    };

    return (
        <Box className="MuiSelect-box" sx={{minWidth: 50}}>
            <FormControl fullWidth>
                <Select
                    className="MuiSelect-select"
                    labelId="currency-select-label"
                    id="currency-select"
                    value={baseCurrency.id}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                >
                    <MenuItem value={CurrencyUtils.currencies.EUR.id}>EUR</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value={CurrencyUtils.currencies.USD.id}>USD</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value={CurrencyUtils.currencies.BTC.id}>BTC</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value={CurrencyUtils.currencies.ETH.id}>ETH</MenuItem>
                </Select>
            </FormControl>
        </Box>
    );
}
```

The problem is that when user chooses an item from the `Select` component, it behaves as if user had clicked on the `Link` inside the Navbar, hence re-directing user to the `Link`'s `to` props i.e. '/'.

Instead, I'd like user to stay on the current Route after interacting with `Select` component, and only call `stateChanger`.

How to implement this ?

Comment: One of the main reasons to ***not*** place interactive elements within other interactive elements. Better to separate these elements. Can you [edit] to include all relevant code you are working with and have an issue using?

Comment: That makes sense. Any workaround to include Select component inside the Navbar ? Or can you recommend a better location for such element, which should be visible from every routes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't nest interactive DOM elements within other interactive DOM elements. You *could* fix this by stopping propagation of the click event in the `select` element, i.e. prevent the event from bubbling up to the link element, but this would still result in poor UI.

If you just need to render the `BaseCurrencySelect` component in the `Navbar` along with the links, then a trivial solution is to unnest `BaseCurrencySelect` and render it as a sibling component to any links.

Example:

```
const Navbar = ({ baseCurrency, stateChanger }) => {
  return (
    <div className='navbar'>
      <Link to='/'>
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="App Name" />
        <h1 className='app_name'>My App Name</h1>
      </Link>

      <BaseCurrencySelect
        baseCurrency={baseCurrency}
        stateChanger={stateChanger}
      />            
    </div>
  );
};
```